# Webservices performance: Cross server vs same server

Tags: web-services, drupal, hosting

My client has site in Drupal, I created webservices to expose data on mobile site. My question: Is there any difference in web service performance if Drupal site and mobile site are on same server VS on different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It  will be quicker if they are on the same server as the request won't have to go out into the internet.

Comment: I am using RESTful web-services which use absolute path to send http request to server. Will it still be better to use same server for both sites?

Comment: Use localhost as the domain and it should be quicker

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If one app is on server, server is fast. Else server is slower and slower.